# My "People Reached (Impact)" jumped from 50k to over 260k+

Tags: support, people-reached

My SO Impact count jumped to over 260k+ in less than 1week. I did not do anything special. Just answered one question or two last week. Usually I would get around 1k impact in 7days. Looks like a bug, hence reporting here.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506104/user1506104?tab=reputation), you got an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection/42826000#42826000) 2 days ago.  That question had ~207k views, which added to your prior ~54k views, for the new total of ~261k.

The upvote caused the ~207k views to be added to your count since it bumped your answer from a score of +4 to a score of +5, which apparently caused it to meet the criteria for an answer to count toward your views:

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count
>
> –["We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/351012)

Before that upvote to +5, your answer was both undeleted and had a >0 score, but it didn't qualify under one of the other conditions.