# What's wrong with having a "vanity metric"?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I noticed that [the new profile changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) included the removal of **profile views** because it's a "vanity metric." I would argue that reputation on SO is 90% vanity anyways, so why remove profile views?

1. If people visit SO strictly to "help others," they probably still enjoy gaining rep, which is vanity.
2. If you're here to increase your skills by answering/asking questions, the same logic applies. With higher rep comes pride in or admiration of one's own achievements. Hence vanity.

Why the sudden shift in perception?

EDIT: I just noticed [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368303/1032701) in the profile changes discussion that offers another perspective on this metric. Thought I'd include it here.

Comment: Because the "reached" metric is far more important, and as it makes Askers look more valuable than Answerers (who are validated by Profile Views) /sarcasm.

Comment: Somewhat tongue in cheek answer: one would recommend that the definition of 'vanity' inherently describes what's "wrong" with it (Note, I personally want to see these things remain/added back to our profiles, personally).

Comment: There's no real difference between the metrics. I imagine it's harder to get a lot of profile views. If you want a lot of reputation, you can keep posting and new stuff will be ripe for votes. I doubt other users keep loading the profiles of a one to them known contributor, so I'm going to guess that the metric doesn't satisfy addictive gamification. You want metrics that users can actively see rising all the time.

Comment: @Larnu How does "reached" give importance to Askers?  The reached amount includes both questions and answers?  Is there some weighting there?

Comment: It just a really dumb calculation, @Matt ,where answers are second class citizens. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367373/6083675)

Comment: Perhaps because it measures the attractiveness of one's profile picture, for the most part?

Comment: If anything was a vanity metric, I'd have to think [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) would be high on that list.

Comment: Profile views could be bots.

Comment: Why not take it a step further and get rid of usernames and profile avatars completely. That would give those useless hats a certain showoff/vanity point. Then we'd be just one step away from running a full circle on it, and being very close to what 4chan always had and never changed - no usernames.

Comment: @Shark most likely, with a quality of answers in line with 4chan, I would expect.

Comment: @SergeyA 4chan had some really good things on it, so if we're actually going to use it as a descriptor, we should be aiming for the best 10% of it. Not the utter garbage part of it. Aren't SO's review queues filled up with similar content already?

Comment:  *You're so vain ... I bet you think this profile's about you..* ‎

Answer (score 122):

> Why the sudden shift in perception?

I think you are looking for a meaningful reason where clearly there is none. Somebody higher up didn't like it, and that's it. After all, they even removed the visit calendar deeming it "potentially toxic", which is another completely arbitrary and subjective reason.

Whether or not such metrics are interesting or fun to have is unfortunately subjective. I too would have preferred for them to stay. The only real answer is that the SE team has been pushing random updates without consulting the community for quite a while now, and they don't seem to care much about feedback or constructive criticism.

Comment: [Insert obligatory comment about SE corporate not caring a whit about what their communities think or want here]

Comment: To SE corporate: Admittedly, I don't necessarily think that all that you do is *"they don't care"*, as this answer claims. There must be some part of the actions that are mistakes or different opinions as we are all human. However, I did upvote this answer. Because even if my rational brain says that it cant be all completely lack of caring, it does *feel* like it, and that is a think that you do really need to tackle, as its what the community *feels* that its happening.

Comment: What's probably even more damning is that the change as considered not just worth the effort, but also **more** important than the other changes demanded by the SO community. We understand SO can't fix everything that needs to be fixed overnight, but at least we'd expect them to prioritize the essential things.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed. However, in this case, I just found it almost comical that the reason was "vanity." It's not so much the arbitrary subjectivity of it. It's that the reason itself is illogical; bordering on hypocritical. Subjectively speaking, that is :)

Comment: Also, I wanted to point out that your assumption _clearly there is none_ could simply be incorrect. Perhaps a decision _was_ made by the SO team that explicitly deems vanity a thing to be shunned. Perhaps one of the designers read Ecclesiastes before coming to work... We simply don't know.

Comment: @silencedogood "clearly there is none" speaking of a "meaningful reason". I don't find "it's a vanity metric" a meaningful reason.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I agree with your comment entirely. Just to clarify I don't feel like they don't care at all, they just "don't care much" as I say in my answer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli And here we are, back to subjectivity. They may have sat around a campfire speaking for hours about vanity. Then, inspired by the earth shaking depth of the conversation, someone dropped the bomb; "vanity metric." My point is, they may very well feel that their thought process behind "vanity metric" is utterly and entirely meaningful.

Comment: So, soon the top x% metric will also disappear. Vanity all the way. And if the calendar could drive people into burn-out, that one surely can, if you're sensitive to it. All confirming the randomness of such decisions.

Comment: @silencedogood touché. Indeed this is merely my opinion, I don't think the subjective decision of some group of employees without community feedback is a meaningful reason to apply a change.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Agreed. Bottom line, as others have mentioned at length; cash is king.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that profile views is even a good vanity metric, it's an entirely irrelevant metric. "People reached" is a good vanity metric, it's often a surprisingly large number so you can feel good about how many people you helped. In comparison, how many people looked at your profile is pretty much irrelevant and also not impressive. There are many different reasons why someone would look at a user profile, not all of them are positive.

I'd argue that calling it a vanity metric is oversimplifying the case, but I would agree that this is probably the least useful and least interesting metric on the user profile. I wouldn't remove it because it's a vanity metric, but because it is a boring and bad vanity metric.

Comment: I hesitate to call “people reached” a metric, much less a good metric. You can inflate the number by millions when your answer has only been seen by 5 people, if you answered a question that already had millions of views and all 5 people upvote your answer. See here:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367373/6083675

Comment: @Laurel it's a bad metric, but a good vanity metric ;-). It makes you feel good, but it's not an accurate metric in many cases.

Comment: (just pontificating here) I'm fairly certain "profile views" was just ported over to Stack Overflow originally because it had always been a popular/common feature in phpBB and Invision forum software (and other popular forum software).

Comment: 9/10 I'm looking at your profile because you're a highish-rep user who posted a dumb question and I'm checking your language tags to see if I should cut some slack for working with an unfamiliar stack. Probably not great for the ego.

Comment: I still think that's an important metric if you are using SO as a way to get a job. That it isn't a metric important for some people doesn't mean it doesn't have value (not talking to you in particular, Mad Scientist)

Comment: Many people are interested in it, I've seen many complaints about it being removed. It takes up almost no space and it's useful for some. Why removing it?

Comment: @TamásSengel counterpoint - it takes up some space and it's not useful to others. Why keep it? It seems quite easy to present only one side, isn't it?

Comment: @VLAZ because it's useful for many, that makes the net "usefulness" positive, no?. It's not like having it its *detrimental* for anyone

Comment: @Lamak [citation needed] on the number of people who find it useful vs those that don't.

Comment: but what I'm saying that for people that don't, it doesn't affect them...so even if it's useful for few people, it's better than removing it